# How can I count the number of lines matching a pattern returned from a linux command

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, grep

How  can I  count the  number  of  lines matching a pattern returned from a  linux command

I want  the number  of  lines  returned beginning with 'foo' , so if I  pipe  the  output to grep will this  work?

```
cat | grep -c ^foo
```

Comment: Why do you even ask, if you answered the question by yourself. Or simply check with your next nearest shell.

Comment: Because there may be  a  better way

Comment: Useless use of cat. `grep -c pattern file`. Yes it's not that much but as soon as you run that thru a loop that runs a couple of thousand times you'll want to save on forks

Comment: Then you could instead ask for alternate ways. Also Server Horror's comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
cat | grep ^foo | wc -l
```

TO show how many lines containing foo are there.

Answer (score 5):

Per Server Horror's comment:

`grep -c pattern file`

Answer (score 3):

From grep man page:

> ****General Output Control****
>
> ```
>     -c, --count      Suppress normal output;
> ```
>
> instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  With the -v, --invert-match 
>   option  (see below), count non-matching lines.
>   (-c is specified by POSIX.)